# deleting XML node in PHP result to not deleting the input value

Tags: php, xml

I am newbie I am trying to delete the row of what value I  input but it keeps in deleting the first row and ignoring what I typed.Thanks in advance for help any help will be really appreciated.

Try.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person>
<Student>
    <id>003</id>
    <name>k</name>
    <age>18</age>
</Student>

<Student>
    <id>004</id>
    <name>q</name>
    <age>19</age>
</Student>

<Student>
    <id>005</id>
    <name>a</name>
    <age>20</age>
</Student>
```

Delete Form code:

```
<head>

<title>Delete Record</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="delete.php">
        ID to delete:<input name="id" type="text"/><br/>
        <input type="Submit" value= "Delete Record">
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

and delete.php

```
    <?php

   $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('try.xml');
    $root   = $xmldoc->documentElement;

    $items = $root->getElementsByTagName('Student')->item(0);
     $old=$root->removeChild($items);



     $test=$xmldoc->save('try.xml');
     if($test)
      echo "Successfully deleted";
     ?>

     <a href="index.php">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have indicated in your code `item(0) and removeChild($items)` that is what triggers it to remove always the first value.

Comment: how can i delete the input value not the first value? any advice?